# dotnet core 3.1 IIS Error "An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions (10013)"

Tags: c#, .net, iis, .net-core

I've dotnet core 3.1 project. I launched a few machines on iis. But today i can't launched the app on iis. I can launch with "dotnet <app.dll>" command and everything's good. But when i launch on IIS, it gives this error.

"crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
Unable to start Kestrel.
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10013): An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError error, String callerName)"

Any suggestion ?

PS: I checked my ports in use with command netstat -o. There is no using from any application

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68272081/asp-net-core-unable-to-start-kestrel-an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in Sounds like the same issue.

Comment: I tried but nothing happened

Comment: It may be caused by a firewall, you can try to disable the firewall and try again.

Comment: Customer is using Windows Defender. I tried when Defender closed but nothing happened. App is running with dotnet command correctly but didnt work on iis

Comment: You can try to use `netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp` to list the reserved ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found my solution on my own. I removed **UseKestrel()** line from program.cs and everything's good.

```
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddCommandLine(args).Build();

       return  Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                webBuilder.UseKestrel(); **//remove this line.**
                webBuilder.UseUrls();
                webBuilder.UseIISIntegration();
                
            }).ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                services.AddHostedService<MonitorWorker>();
                services.AddHostedService<TransferWorker>();
            });

    }
```

Answer (score 20):

`netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp`

Look at the ports listed and see if it overlaps with your port.

If so, rebooting your PC or changing the port has fixed this for me.

I'm using port `56240`, Windows Update sometimes takes that range.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is most likely due to a Windows Update that restricted access to certain ports on Windows machines. The details are [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1486417/unable-to-start-kestrel-getting-an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way).

You can view a list of which ports are excluded from your user by running this command:

```
netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp
```

[image]

Changing port number should fix the issue.